# Do Hard IPs in FPGA require instantiation?

Tags: fpga

As hard IPs are already fabricated on the fpga, is it right that such ips do not have to be instantiated like soft ips?
if it is not correct then why should i instantiate an hard ip as it is already fabricated on the fpga?

Answer (score 8):

You do need to instantiate hard IPs in order to tell the software to:

- Enable it (otherwise it will be disabled to save power)
- Set its parameters (most are configurable) including clock source, etc
- Connect it to FPGA fabric (or maybe a hard IP bus) in the way you want,

Comment: thank you. i understand now. so it is like instantiating a bram. bram is hard ip. but i have to instantiate it in order to write and read from it. correct?

Comment: @JenParker You could think about it as declaring it. You're not "instantiating" it in the strictest sense but in Verilog/VHDL there is little distinction from the user perspective since the difference is all under the hood. Things aren't set up such that all the hard IP in each device has pre-assigned unique labels that are always in play such that you can refer to them with no prior setup.

Comment: For the BRAM you could say you're "instantiating" the connections to it

Comment: @bobflux I think that's the major point. A counterexample (i.e. what /doesn't/ happen) would be where the description of e.g. a block of BRAM were in some way stored on the chip, and you had to instantiate it into general purpose cells one or more times to use it.

Comment: When instantiating BRAM you can also fill it with data